# How to use event of onWrite

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I want to get the value of post_id in the onWrite(( change,context)
Please Help?

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const request = require('request-promise')


exports.indexPostsToElastic = functions.database.ref('/posts/{post_id}')
.onWrite(event => {

    let post_id = event.params.post_id;
});

exports.indexPostsToElastic = functions.database.ref('/posts/{post_id}')
.onWrite(( change,context) => {

    let postData = change.after.val();


    console.log('Indexing post:', postData);

    let elasticSearchConfig = functions.config().elasticsearch;
    let elasticSearchUrl = elasticSearchConfig.url + 'posts/post/' + post_id;
    let elasticSearchMethod = postData ? 'POST' : 'DELETE';

    let elasticSearchRequest = {
        method: elasticSearchMethod,
        url: elasticSearchUrl,
        auth:{
            username: elasticSearchConfig.username,
            password: elasticSearchConfig.password,
        },
        body: postData,
        json: true
      };

      return request(elasticSearchRequest).then(response => {
         console.log("ElasticSearch response", response);
      });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The signature of `onWrite` has changed. To both *get* the value from the parameters and use it, make sure you only have one function and then get the parameter value:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const request = require('request-promise')


exports.indexPostsToElastic = functions.database.ref('/posts/{post_id}')
.onWrite((change, context) => {

    let post_id = context.params.post_id; // get post_id value from params

    let postData = change.after.val();


    console.log('Indexing post:', postData);

    let elasticSearchConfig = functions.config().elasticsearch;
    let elasticSearchUrl = elasticSearchConfig.url + 'posts/post/' + post_id;
    let elasticSearchMethod = postData ? 'POST' : 'DELETE';

    let elasticSearchRequest = {
        method: elasticSearchMethod,
        url: elasticSearchUrl,
        auth:{
            username: elasticSearchConfig.username,
            password: elasticSearchConfig.password,
        },
        body: postData,
        json: true
      };

      return request(elasticSearchRequest).then(response => {
         console.log("ElasticSearch response", response);
      });
});
```

Also see:

- the [Cloud Functions documentation on handling event data from the realtime database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events#handle_event_data)
- the [Cloud Functions documentation on upgrading your code to 1.0](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff)